# how to get Algolia object snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I have a product listings catalogue and am trying to search through it. I decided to use Algolia search. I was able to upload my firebase database to Algolia. I now have an indice in this format

```
  objectID:5133-01-371-1830-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1508966908235
  NSN:5133-01-371-1830
  Nomenclature:COUNTERSINK
  Category:FSC 5133 - Drill Bits, Counterbores, and Countersinks: Hand and Machine
  Product_Manuf:Neol
  Ava_QTY:3
  Price:434
  ProductImageUrl:https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com
  Product_Condition:New
  SellerID:OkqcPp3x900878v6v6688g8
  Shipping_cost:3
  Shipping_option:(Std US Dom) 4 - 14 business days
  Time:10/25/2017, 5:28:28 PM
```

ObjectID is each listing ID. I then figured out how to do autocomplete search using this code

```
autocomplete('#aa-search-input',
{ hint: true }, {
source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 5}),
displayKey: 'NSN',
templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
      return '<span>' +
        suggestion._highlightResult.NSN.value + '</span><span>' ;
    }
}

});
```

in firebase I can use this code to get a snapshot of all the data for the id

```
 var itemdetailref = Cataloguedatabase.ref('/Listings/'+ listingID);

 return itemdetailref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){

 })
```

and then use the snapshot to populate my html field.

how can I get an Algolia snapshot (similar to firebase snapshot) of the clicked object in autocomplete? can this even be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen to the `autocomplete:selected` event, which has the complete data in the index.

see https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#events